# Печать страницы с передачей параметров

Tags: jquery, javascript

Нужно сделать печать внешней страницы без перезагрузки. И притом передать ей данные.

Смотрел в сторону `jQuery-printPage-plugin`, но как передать к странице свои данные, в документации ничего не сказано, можно ли использовать параметр `data`.

Можете поделится предложениями, как это реализовать?

Comment: Это же не единственный плагин. [Посмотрите другие](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-print-page-options/), с более подходящими опциями.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему просто. Закодировал данные и передал через гет.